# VBA - UserForm - How to restore default Label caption while loaded

Tags: vba, userform

I created an UserForm, and I'm updating a lot of things on the `ComboBox_Change` event, including some Labels' caption using this :

```
Me.Lab_LastVal.Caption = Replace(Me.Lab_LastVal.Caption, "Currency", Me.ComboBox1.Value)
Me.Lab_NewVal.Caption = Replace(Me.Lab_NewVal.Caption, "Currency", Me.ComboBox1.Value)
```

The problem is that when I do it once, it won't work because `Currency` will have disappeared of the `Caption`...

I could save the initial labels in an array on runtime to reapply after, or even use the previous value of the combobox, but my question is really : **How to restore default Label caption while the UserForm is loaded?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any other way to restore default caption, so **I saved the initial labels** in an array on runtime to **reapply them after** when it is needed.